# How to capture the traceback for an error in python along with source code?

Tags: python, traceback

When I run a vscode notebook cell or a python file with these contents:

```py
def foo():
    return 4/0  # This will cause a division by zero exception

foo()
```

I get the following error traceback which is very meaningful and tells me at what line along with the line of code that errors:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[12], line 4
      1 def foo():
      2     return 4/0  # This will cause a division by zero exception
----> 4 foo()

Cell In[12], line 2, in foo()
      1 def foo():
----> 2     return 4/0

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

However when I run the program using a `exec` block I am unable to see the source code. How do I capture this?

```py
import traceback
import sys

code = """def foo():
    return 4/0  # This will cause a division by zero exception

foo()
"""

try:
    exec(code)
except Exception as e:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/folders/fd/f7mj1ws56pq6xvyzj4zv1r_m0000gn/T/ipykernel_39670/712868849.py", line 11, in <module>
    exec(code)
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 2, in foo
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Answer (score 2):

The traceback printing mechanism relies on being able to read the line from disk (using the `linecache` module).

For `exec`'d code, there is no disk (after all, that's why it's saying `File "<string>", line 2`).

[Looking at what `traceback` is doing](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/16dcce21768ba381996a88ac8c255bf1490b3680/Lib/traceback.py#L326) you can patch `linecache.getline` to do a special thing for `<string>`s:

```
import traceback
import linecache
import unittest.mock

code = """def foo():
    return 4/0  # This will cause a division by zero exception

foo()
"""

orig_getline = linecache.getline


def new_getline(filename, lineno, *args, **kwargs):
    if filename == "<string>":
        return code.splitlines()[lineno - 1]
    return orig_getline(filename, lineno, *args, **kwargs)


with unittest.mock.patch("linecache.getline", new_getline):
    try:
        exec(code)
    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc()
```

et voilà:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\build\so-misc\so76878031.py", line 23, in <module>
    exec(code)
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
    foo()
  File "<string>", line 2, in foo
    return 4/0  # This will cause a division by zero exception
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```